# In pandas namespace, how do we find the TimeZone it is adopting ? For example 'US/Eastern' for a US locale system

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have been exploring the methods and properties in pd.Timestamp, and pd.DatetimeIndex, but so far have not been able to find a way to get the TimeZone that pandas is adopting; like 'US/Eastern' for a US locale system.

One would assume that pandas would adopt the TimeZone specified in the system locale when converting datetime string like '2022-03-03 17:15:00' into Epoch value.
We could find timezone information using the time module:
time.tzname => ('EST','EDT')

I am wondering in pandas, how do we get the default timezone it is adopting ?

Comment: It seems that when no TimeZone information is specified, so called timezone naive mode; pd.Timestamp, and pd.DatetimeIndex would treat the datetime string like '2022-03-03 17:15:00' as UTC time, and calculate Epoch accordingly ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe its naive and no tz is assumed.

You can of course specify utc=True and then convert to a specific tz.

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "START_TIME": ["2022-06-27 09:30:19", "2022-08-20 11:55:25"],
    "STOP_TIME": ["2022-06-27 12:30:00", "2022-08-20 13:00:00"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

          START_TIME            STOP_TIME
0  2022-06-27 09:30:19  2022-06-27 12:30:00
1  2022-08-20 11:55:25  2022-08-20 13:00:00

for column in [x for x in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains("time", case=False)]]:
    df[column] = (
        pd.to_datetime(df[column], utc=True)
        .dt.tz_convert("America/New_York")
    )

print(df)


                 START_TIME                 STOP_TIME
0 2022-06-27 05:30:19-04:00 2022-06-27 08:30:00-04:00
1 2022-08-20 07:55:25-04:00 2022-08-20 09:00:00-04:00
```

If you know the data is already in a specific tz but it is naive you can also make it tz aware.

```
for column in [x for x in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains("time", case=False)]]:
    df[column] = (
        pd.to_datetime(df[column], utc=False)
        .dt.tz_localize("America/New_York")
    )

print(df)

                 START_TIME                 STOP_TIME
0 2022-06-27 09:30:19-04:00 2022-06-27 12:30:00-04:00
1 2022-08-20 11:55:25-04:00 2022-08-20 13:00:00-04:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip :
   utc=True/False